# Curator LeaderLatch EOFException on shutdown

Tags: apache-curator

We use LeaderLatch to select leader on my cluster.

we use it like this:

```
leaderLatch.addListener(new LeaderLatchListener() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void isLeader() {
                                      // create leader tasks runner
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void notLeader() {
                                        // shutdown leader tasks runner
                                });

                                leaderLatch.start();
                                leaderLatch.await();
```

We also have a graceful shutdown process:

```
                CloseableUtils.closeQuietly(leaderLatch);
```

now, the problem is when I shutdown a non-leader instance, the `await()` method throws a EOFException.

This is the code from LeaderLatch itself:

```
public void await() throws InterruptedException, EOFException
    {
        synchronized(this)
        {
            while ( (state.get() == State.STARTED) && !hasLeadership.get() )
            {
                wait();
            }
        }
        if ( state.get() != State.STARTED )
        {
            throw new EOFException();
        }
    }
```

since I have closed it - the state is not STARTED but CLOSED so empty EOFException is thrown.

Is there a better way?

We use `curator-recepies-4.2.0`

Regards,
Ido

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contract for `await()` is to not return until it owns the lock. It has no way of indicating that you don't own the lock other than to throw an exception. I suggest you use the version of await that takes a timeout and returns a boolean. You can then close the lock and check the result of `await()`. Do this in a loop if you want.